# batch file doesnt work on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I am trying to execute a simple batch file with following contents..

```
ECHO OFF 
::CMD will no longer show us what command it’s executing(cleaner)
ECHO As a network admin, I’m getting tired of having to type these commands in!             
:: Print some text
IPCONFIG /ALL 
:: Outputs tons of network information into the command prompt
PAUSE 
:: Lets the user read the important network information
PING www.google.com 
:: Ping google to figure out if we’ve got internet!
ECHO All done pinging Google. 
::Print some text
PAUSE
```

But, nothing happens except a flash of command prompt. PAUSE does not seem to have any effect. Please help.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `IPCONFIG` bit in your script is not actually another batch script which happens to have the same name as the `IPCONFIG` command and which is accessible to your script just by the name?

Comment: just as a side note, you could try [sysinternals bginfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557) - great tool for any support desk

Comment: @AndriyM.. I cross checked...There is no other batch file named as IPCONFIG..

Comment: Can you get the script to pause before `ipconfig`, to see if thats whats causing the problem.

Comment: What happens if you open a CMD prompt and then run your batch file?

Comment: I think an error is happening with ipconfig /all - like aphoria said, what happens in a CMD prompt window when you run the program, if its an error, youll see it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have administrator privileges to run ipconfig.

Comment: I have admin privileges as i can easily run IP config through command prompt. But the same thing I want to do using batch file. I guess no batch file is working properly on my system.